# Creating a search option in Nodejs with database mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a search option by name in node.js and it will search local database, if it finds the name it will display in webpage. But I'm getting the error in this syntax : user.find({id : findname}, which I have used in below code.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var findname = req.body.findname;
 res.render('detail', { title: 'Detail' });
});
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/student');
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
id : Number,
name : String,
email : String,
age : Number,
college : String
});

var user = mongoose.model('stud', testSchema, 'stud');

router.post('/show', function(req, res){
  user.find({name : findname}, function(err, docs){
       res.render('detail',{users:docs});
  });
```

});

Comment: What is the problem, and what is the goal? What is the expected result, and what is the actual result? Why is `findname` declared after it is used?

Comment: Awesome of you to tell us ^^ But if you have a problem, please describe it, provide some logs, say what you wanted to achieve :)

Comment: I have edited the question and explained my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is you've defined your `findname` variable in one function and are trying to use it in another. In order to accomplish what you're looking for, your `router.post` function should probably look something like this:

```
router.post('/show', function(req, res){
  var findname = req.body.findname
  user.find({name : findname}, function(err, docs){
    res.render('detail',{users:docs});
  });
});
```

Make sure you're using the correct middleware to populate the `req.body` object as well, or the code still won't work.

Comment: Problem was with syntax : user.find({name : req.body.findname}}, here name should be written like : "name"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the mongoose documentation [Mongoose Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id). The id (and _id) fields are automatically assigned by Mongoose. The id is a virtual getter on the _id, it is a string or hex representation of the _id. Try to change the name of your field ­`id` by `myId`.

Anyway, your `id` is of type number and your try to match it with `findname` which is I guess a string ? Is there a type mismatch here ?

Comment: No, thats not the problem I had changed it to name and still getting the same error.